# Display cannot be detected after resume of standby

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display, docking-station

If I sleep my computer at home, then take it to work and resume it, the second monitor from the video card cannot be detected from the "Screen Resolution" dialog.  (The monitor turns on just fine, but Windows can't "See" it.)

Is there any other way to ask windows to "Look Harder"?

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience with additional keyboard, Windows usually lost it if I plug it before logging in. When I plug it after - it is ok. Maybe you should look for similar scenario with your monitor.